# Networking: how to create a server that lets multiple users talk to each other

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, serversocket

i am trying to create a server that just waits for users to connect (TCP method) and once 2 users connect, the server lets them talk to each other.
because the server waits for an endless amount of users, i know i need to use threads, but- my problem is i don't know how to enable constant read/write flow.

lets say 2 users connected to my server and i want them to talk. each user needs to be able to write as many lines as he wants without waiting for the other user. every program we were shown was more of a "write, wait for input, write again" kind of program(in a simple loop), but i want my program to keep listening for input all the time, and show it when it arrives.
the output is rather simple, i have a JTextField with a listener- so every time the user wants to write he hits 'enter'- and the listener knows to send the output. but how do i keep a constant listener for incoming Strings from the server? is there a special listener that can be used every time the client side detects an input?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use something like IRC protocol, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459. Maybe this will help ? https://github.com/pircbotx/pircbotx